# Filtering a dataframe in Python with specific requirements

Tags: python, filter

I would like to filter a dataframe and having some difficulty to do so.

My dataframe looks as such:

```
+--------+----------+--------+-------+-----+------+------+------+--------+------+----+----+----------+-----+-----+------+------+-------------+------+
|  node  |   date   | isSetl | qual  | run | firm | acct | type | isCust | seg  | ec | cc | currency | lov | sov | isM  | pbc  |   spanReq   | anov |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+-----+------+------+------+--------+------+----+----+----------+-----+-----+------+------+-------------+------+
| oReq   | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   10 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | USD      |     |     | MNT  | CORE |   124073.69 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   10 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | CNY      |     |     |      |      |       43480 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   10 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | USD      |     |     |      |      |      117750 |    0 |
| oReq   | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   10 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | USD      |     |     | INIT | CORE |   124073.69 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   10 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | CNY      |     |     |      |      |       43480 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   10 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | USD      |     |     |      |      |      117750 |    0 |
| oReq   | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   40 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | CNH      |     |     | MNT  | CORE |           0 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   40 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | CNY      |     |     |      |      |      986680 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   40 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     |      |      |    28786701 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   40 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | USD      |     |     |      |      |       67790 |    0 |
| oReq   | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   40 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | CNH      |     |     | INIT | CORE |           0 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   40 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | CNY      |     |     |      |      |      986680 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   40 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     |      |      |    28786701 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   40 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | USD      |     |     |      |      |       67790 |    0 |
| oReq   | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   60 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     | MNT  | CORE | 17381842.35 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   60 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     |      |      |      245850 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   60 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | USD      |     |     |      |      |     2193000 |    0 |
| oReq   | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   60 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     | INIT | CORE | 17381842.35 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   60 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     |      |      |      245850 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   60 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | USD      |     |     |      |      |     2193000 |    0 |
| oReq   | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   70 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     | MNT  | CORE |      163900 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   70 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     |      |      |      163900 |    0 |
| oReq   | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   70 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     | INIT | CORE |      163900 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   70 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     |      |      |      163900 |    0 |
| oReq   | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   80 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     | MNT  | CORE |    25733800 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   80 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     |      |      |    25733800 |    0 |
| oReq   | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   80 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     | INIT | CORE |    25733800 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   80 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     |      |      |    25733800 |    0 |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+-----+------+------+------+--------+------+----+----+----------+-----+-----+------+------+-------------+------+
```

I would like to filter such that i need the rows below INIT in the column 'isM'

Output that I want:

```
+--------+----------+--------+-------+-----+------+------+------+--------+------+----+----+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+------+
|  node  |   date   | isSetl | qual  | run | firm | acct | type | isCust | seg  | ec | cc | currency | lov | sov | isM | pbc | spanReq  | anov |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+-----+------+------+------+--------+------+----+----+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+------+
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   10 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | CNY      |     |     |     |     |    43480 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   10 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | USD      |     |     |     |     |   117750 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   40 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | CNY      |     |     |     |     |   986680 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   40 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     |     |     | 28786701 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   40 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | USD      |     |     |     |     |    67790 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   60 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     |     |     |   245850 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   60 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | USD      |     |     |     |     |  2193000 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   70 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     |     |     |   163900 |    0 |
| curReq | 20190627 | TRUE   | final |   0 | FCG  |   80 | S    | TRUE   | CUST |    |    | HKD      |     |     |     |     | 25733800 |    0 |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+-----+------+------+------+--------+------+----+----+----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+------+
```

How do i filter such i can get the output to be as such?

Need some guidance in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  It adds two temporary columns to the dataframe (`df`):

- `temp` to keep track of rows where the `isM` column equals `INIT`. These rows will later be removed.
- `temp_ism` fills forward the `isM` column so to find all rows following `INIT`.

  ```
  df = df.assign(temp=df['isM'].eq('INIT'), temp_ism=df['isM'].ffill())
  # Drop the first `INIT` rows (`~df['temp']`) but retain the following rows.
  result = df[df['temp_ism'].eq('INIT') & ~df['temp']].iloc[:, :-2]  # Drop the two temporary columns.
  df = df.iloc[:, :-2]  # Drop the two temporary columns from the original dataframe.
  ```